# Integration Question Help: $\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2} dy$

Tags: integration

How to integrate the following function:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{1+y^2} dy$$

### -----------------------

Comment: You may try a u-sub: $y=sint$ Show us what you get then

Comment: Use the change of variables: $y=\cos x$

Comment: $$y=\sin t$$ then divide by $$\sec^2t$$

Comment: i get 1/ 1+2tant in the end but don't know how to continue

Answer (score 0):

Using the substitution $y=\sin t$, the integral becomes

$$\int\frac{\cos^2t\,dt}{1+\sin^2t}=\int\frac{dt}{1+2\tan^2t}$$

Now you can make the substitution $u=\sqrt 2\tan t$, and the integral becomes

$$\int\frac{2\,du}{(1+u^2)(2+u^2)}$$

Decompose this in partial fractions and recognize that each are derivatives of an inverse tangent.